# 1985 - 1995 Scifi book aimed at teens set on the moon

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

Looking for a sci-fi book that I got out of the library several times when i was a kid in between 1985 and 1995 (I think).
Was set on the moon. Young man returning to visit, discovers a conspiracy and girlfriend helps investigate. Had a tank type transport on the front cover. Was aimed at teenagers I believe.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you remember what kind of conspiracy?  Did people live underground or in domes?

Answer (score 10):

*Earthdark* by Monica Hughes would fit. Published in 1977, but I found it in a library in the late 80s/early 90s. Young adult style, so that also matches.

The older [covers](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?17446) have a lunar rover that does look somewhat like a tank.

[image: Cover of 'Earthdark' by Monica Hughes, showing the title above a tank-like lunar rover travelling on the moon, with the Earth hanging in the sky in the background]

The protagonist, Kepler Masterman, lives on the moon but has recently returned having spent time on Earth. I sadly can't recall all of the details of the plot, but what I do remember, and the Amazon summary, fits your description:

> The dangerous and sinister repercussions that follow threaten his and his girlfriend's lives.

Answer (score 4):

Probably too old and not else much to go on, but "tank type transport on the front cover" made me immediately flash back to this one from my elementary school library:

***[Moon of Mutiny](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?212949)*, by Lester del Rey** (1961)

[image: Cover of "Moon of Mutiny" by Lester del Rey. The cover shows a long vehicle with treads on the cratered surface of the moon, heading towards a landed spaceship. The Earth is visible in the starry sky.]

The protagonist *is* returning to the moon, but I don't remember a girlfriend.

Answer (score 4):

One book which I read that possibly could be the one asked about is *Vandals of the Void* by Jack Vance (1953).

A teenager from the Venus colony visits his father on the Moon, and gets involved with the skullduggery of space pirates based on the moon.

However, the cover seen here doesn't have a vehicle on the surface of the Moon.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandals_of_the_Void

It does show a spaceship and a much smaller vehicle above the surface of the Moon.

Here is a link to depictions of the covers of various editions of *Vandals of the Void*.

https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?276631

Of course there have probably been tens or hundreds of other stories about teenagers uncovering sinister plots on the Moon.